# I want to support plural concepts (e.g. the utterances "look up burger" and "look up burgers") - how do I do this?

Tags: bixby

I would like Bixby to treat a concept's plural counterpart to be recognized as the concept itself.

How do I ensure that Bixby can recognize "look up burger" and "look up burgers" are both referring to "burger"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To support both "burger" and "burgers" you will need to add both forms to vocabulary

If the subject can be picked up from context (lexically) such as with “get me an uber to ", then whether or not the subject is plural doesn’t matter much.

If the query relies on vocabulary such as with "look up burger" versus "look up burgers", perhaps because it is not well-discriminated by its unannotated terms or it uses enum values, then you will have to specifically add the plural forms to vocabulary yourself.

Example of Enum:

[image: Example of how the Enum would need to be set up]

Example of accompanying Vocabulary file:

[image: Example of the accompanying Vocabulary file]